# Hazelcast cache reload

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using multiple hazelcast IMaps which are eagerly loaded using MapLoader. It currently takes 8-10 minutes to load the cache/maps completely. I need to refresh cache once everyday. During the refresh interval all requests start going to database which is very slow. How can I improve the performance of the application?

1. Would increasing the number of database connections help in reducing the time to load data?
2. For cache reload, is it possible to somehow evict and load data partition by partition or node by node, so that some of the incoming requests can be served from cache rather than database?

Comment: Why do you need to reload the cache at regular intervals?

IMHO, it's far better to replace cache items when they are updated in the database. Here's a way to do it: https://github.com/hazelcast-demos/evergreen-cache

Comment: Also, @Priyanka your scenario seems like a valid case for some kind of blue-green deployment. This is something you can try.

Comment: @Priyanka were you able to figure this out?